# Generic string router with DB in Asp.net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, .net-core

I am creating an internet store. And I want to add short URLs for products, categories and so on.
For example:

> store.com/iphone-7-plus

This link should open the page with iPhone 7 plus product.

The logic is:

1. The server receives an URL
2. The server try it against existent routes
3. If there is no any route for this path - **the server looks at a DB and try to find a product or category with such title**.

**Obvious solutions and why are they not applicable:**

The first solution is a new route like that:

```
public class StringRouter : IRouter
{
    private readonly IRouter _defaultRouter;

    public StringRouter(IRouter defaultRouter)
    {
        _defaultRouter = defaultRouter;
    }

    public async Task RouteAsync(RouteContext context)
    {
        // special loggic

        await _defaultRouter.RouteAsync(context);
    }

    public VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(VirtualPathContext context)
    {
        return _defaultRouter.GetVirtualPath(context);
    }
}
```

The problem is I can't provide any access to my DB from `StringRouter`.

The second solution is:

```
public class MasterController : Controller
{
    [Route("{path}")]
    public IActionResult Map(string path)
    {
        // some logic
    }
}
```

The problem is the server receive literally all callings like `store.com/robots.txt`

So the question is still open - could you please advise me some applicable solution?

Comment: Make route more specific for products, for example `store.com/products/iphone-7-plus`, then your last option will work without receiving "everything".

Comment: The problem is I already have an internet store worked on NotCommerce. So I already have URLs like store.com/iphone-7-plus in all search engines, marketplaces and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For accessing `DbContext`, you could try :

```
     using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

    public async Task RouteAsync(RouteContext context)
    {           
        var dbContext = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<RouterProContext>();
        var products = dbContext.Product.ToList();
        await _defaultRouter.RouteAsync(context);
    }
```

You also could try `Middleware` to check whether the reuqest is not exist, and then return the expected response.

```
            public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {                
            app.Use(async (context,next) => {

                await next.Invoke();
                // add your own business logic to check this if statement
                if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404)
                {
                        var db = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<RouterProContext>();
                        var users = db.Users.ToList();
                        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Request From Middleware");
                }
            });
            //your rest code
        }
```